# How do I specify env variable for each worker in remote host?

Tags: ray

I am a recent converter to ray from python multiprocessing library.
I have a custom resource with four chips and I need to specify environment variable. e.g. `VISIBLE_DEVICE=0` to use them in parallel.

So in multiprocessing, I would always create 4 processes which acquire 1 chip each by

```
class P(Process):
    def run(self, chip_id):
        os.environ['VISIBLE_DEVICE']=chip_id
        fn()
```

Is there a way I can do something similar in ray? Like

1. Spawn 4 ray remote workers only in each host
2. Each worker gets different env variable before running function.

Answer (score 1):

To spawn only one worker in each host you could try the STRICT_SPREAD strategy for placement groups: https://docs.ray.io/en/master/placement-group.html

To pass an environment variable to a Ray Task or Actor, you can use the argument `override_environment_variables` (https://docs.ray.io/en/master/package-ref.html#ray-remote). For example:

```
my_task.options(override_environment_variables={'VISIBLE_DEVICE': 1234}).remote()
```